# Ventura 13.2.1 (macbook air m1) file picker usage: can't select a symlink leading to a directory or a /Volumes/xxx itself

Tags: macos

Can't select a mounted volume in utorrent directory picker either directly or via a symlink I made. How can I get around it?

/dev/disk4s2 on /Volumes/mov1TB (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled)

the symlink is

> lrwxr-xr-x   1 agraph  staff   19 Mar 23 19:30 mov ->
> /Volumes/mov1TB/mov

mov is an existing directory in

> drwxr-xr-x@ 18 agraph  staff  612 Mar 19 12:08 /Volumes/mov1TB/mov

Here's the (utterly useless) directory picker in uTorrent

[image]

Comment: Your words are our eyes. What version of macOS? What Mac? What is the mounted volume. Give us some information to work with.

Comment: I know this frustrating, but this appears to be a limitation of your App.  Have you queried the devs?

Comment: Now that you mentioned it I asked on bittorrent forums. Thq Q is in moderation. Thanks.

Comment: How did you mount "mov1TB"? I just tried, when I select "Create torrent" I see my SMB-mounted NAS directories listed in the screenshot you show above.

Comment: plug and pray of usb hdd. "It just works"

Answer (score 0):

uTorrent is unuseable when a folder on a mounted volume has to be used.
**Switched to another torrent client.** That's the solution until/if uTorrent gets fixed.

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: This answer is *very* clear @Thinkr. What do you not understand about it?

Comment: It was clear before @Thinkr. Making the solution bold and adding “until it gets fixed” doesn’t change the solution or the clarity thereof one iota.